# can't retrieve the wanted data out from database and have error in closing connection

Tags: asp.net

I have created an ASP.NET application in Visual Studio 2010. I am having trouble in retrieving the data i wanted from the two dates i selected from the date picker. once i select the 2 dates, it just keep displaying all the data out and not the dates that i have selected and i also have problem closing a connection as it gave me this error : "Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count."

This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        //getting data

        string startdate = (string)(Session["startdate"]);
        string enddate = (string)(Session["enddate"]);

        DateTime one = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
        DateTime two = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);

        if (two >= one)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source="";Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN '" + startdate+ "' AND '" + enddate+ "'", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            conn.Close();
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MCDU-PC34\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ncpsdbb;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "'",conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: i am having error at :  da.selectCommand = cmd . the error shown :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Replace SqlDataAdapter da = null; this with SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your session variables are two correct dates then you should not use string concatenation to pass an sql command to your database but you should use a parameterized query

```
 string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM StudentTransactions " + 
                  "WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN @iniDT AND @endDT"
 SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iniDT", one);
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDT",two);
```

This approach will leave the duty to pass in the correct format for the dates to the framework code and you avoid parsing problems and close the door to sql injections attacks.

Comment: i have tried this method but it still display the whole data out.